# How to make a barplot with R from a table?

Tags: r, plot

I have some data in .cvs. I would like to make a simple barplot in R, with this data, but I a little lost in R.

```
Specie   Number
A        18756
V        8608 
R        3350 
P        3312 
O        1627
```

I already have the number of each specie. I just want to plot the results?
A, V, R, P, O are the names of the species.

I am a little confused of what I have to do first? Do I have to convert the table to a matrix? What commands do I have to use in R?

Comment: did you read the data in yet?... how far have you gotten?  Have you read anything at all in terms of documentation?  I believe this is pretty much covered in a number of the introductory documents in the contributed section on the website.

Comment: This is a perfect use case for Deducer or similar.  See this q for other suggestions: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9085/software-for-easy-yet-robust-data-exploration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
y = data.frame(Specie=c('A','V','R','P','O'),Number=c(18756,8608,3350,3312,1627))
barplot(y$Number, names.arg=y$Specie)
```

You would use read.csv (or one of its friends) to read from a file into a Data Frame.

Answer (score 1):

Try `help(barplot)`,  In there you'll find a command that does what you need.  Specifically you'll enter Number as the height argument and Specie for the names.arg argument.