# Make barplot in ggplot2 with summary statistics

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have data, similar to that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936289/how-to-make-a-barplot-with-r-from-a-table), from which I am directly taking Matthew Lundberg's code as an example.

```
y = data.frame(Specie=c('A','V','R','P','O'),Number=c(18756,8608,3350,3312,1627))
```

It is demonstrated how to create a barplot using the `barplot` command:

```
barplot(y$Number, names.arg=y$Specie)
```

How would I do the same thing using `ggplot2` or `qplot`?

The following does not work:

```
library(ggplot2)
y = data.frame(Specie=c('A','V','R','P','O'),Number=c(18756,8608,3350,3312,1627))
qplot(x=y[,2], y=y[,1],  geom="bar", stat="identify")
```

What to do?

Comment: You have several typos. 1) `stat = "identity"`, not "identify". 2) `choice1` isn't defined (at least in your question). Presumably you want `y`, the name of your data.frame. 3) Probably you want the categorical first column (`Specie`) on the x-axis, and the `Number` on the y-axis. You have them reversed currently. If you make those changes you'll have a nice little barplot.

Comment: Concerning 2, that was a mistake.  I meant to do `y` instead.  I edited the code to reflect this.  Thank you for also pointing out the other errors.  I now have a nice plot!