# Side-by-side bars in bar plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

This is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913954/make-barplot-in-ggplot2-with-summary-statistics?noredirect=1#comment42377447_26913954).  Suppose that I have this data:

```
y = data.frame(Specie=c('A','V','R','P','O'),Number=c(18756,8608,3350,3312,1627))
z = data.frame(Specie=c('A','V','R','P','O'),Number=c(17000,1000,8000,5500,9000))
```

Notice that the `Specie` variable is the same across `y` and `z`.

I can create a bar plot for y and z, respectively, by the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x=y[,1], y=y[,2], geom="bar", stat="identity")
qplot(x=z[,1], y=z[,2], geom="bar", stat="identity")
```

How would I consolidate these two plots into one?  The idea would be to have the `y` and `z` bars right beside each other, both within the same associated `Specie` variable.  The bars for `x` would be, eg., blue and the bars for `y` would be, eg., red.

Comment: This is going to be easier if you rbind the data and use a source-indicator variable.

Comment: Another good resource for starting with `ggplot`: [Cookbook For R: Bar and Line Graphs](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = data.frame(Specie=c('A','V','R','P','O'),Number=c(18756,8608,3350,3312,1627))
z = data.frame(Specie=c('A','V','R','P','O'),Number=c(17000,1000,8000,5500,9000))

library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

df=merge(y,z,by=c("Specie"))
names(df)=c("Specie","y","z")

df=melt(df)

ggplot(df,aes(x=Specie,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_bar( stat="identity",position=position_dodge())
```

[image]