# Create Side-by-Side Bar Plot

Tags: plot, stata

I would like to create side-by-side bar plots based on frequencies. An R example is found at [Side-by-side bars in bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916505/side-by-side-bars-in-bar-plot)  Is this possible to do in Stata?

Suppose I have this data:

```
clear
set obs 1000
set seed 1
gen var1 = runiform()*10
set seed 2
gen var2 = runiform()*10
set seed 3
gen var3 = runiform()*10

gen var1_value = "A" if var1<3
replace var1_value = "B" if var1>=3 & var1<=9
replace var1_value = "C" if var1>9

gen var2_value = "A" if var2<4
replace var2_value = "B" if var2>=4 & var2<=6
replace var2_value = "C" if var2>6 

gen var3_value = "A" if var3<1
replace var3_value = "B" if var3>=1 & var3<=3
replace var3_value = "C" if var3>3
```

I can use the user-written commands `tabplot` and `catplot` to plot these individually:

```
capture ssc install tabplot 
tabplot var1_value 
tabplot var2_value
tabplot var3_value

capture ssc install catplot
catplot var1_value
catplot var2_value
catplot var3_value
```

However, I would like these three to be on the same plot, side-by-side by value. If possible, I would like to have many plots side-by-side for each value instead of the 3 in this example.

Comment: "User-installed functions" has been edited to "user-written commands".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The easiest is likely to be a simple restructuring of the data. Following your example, I assume a prior `ssc inst catplot`. Add options such as `asyvars` for razzmatazz like different colours.

```
clear
set obs 1000
set seed 1
gen var1 = runiform()*10
set seed 2
gen var2 = runiform()*10
set seed 3
gen var3 = runiform()*10

gen var1_value = "A" if var1<3
replace var1_value = "B" if var1>=3 & var1<=9
replace var1_value = "C" if var1>9

gen var2_value = "A" if var2<4
replace var2_value = "B" if var2>=4 & var2<=6
replace var2_value = "C" if var2>6 

gen var3_value = "A" if var3<1
replace var3_value = "B" if var3>=1 & var3<=3
replace var3_value = "C" if var3>3

forval j = 1/3 { 
    clonevar value`j' = var`j'_value 
}

gen id = _n 
reshape long value, i(id) j(which) 
catplot which value, asyvars 
catplot value which, asyvars
```