# no side by side bars are shown using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

My question is related with this one:
[Side-by-side bars in bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916505/side-by-side-bars-in-bar-plot) 
I am trying to do the same kind of thing, but I just don't get any data, the axis are filled in. But no visualised graph. I tried to remoddel the data in small steps, but it still did not worked out. I have no clue, why the data is not shown.

```
n<-15
data <- data.frame("number" = c(1:n), 
              "Nasal" = c(15.4, 13.5, 13.3, 12.4, 12.8,
                          13.5, 14.5, 13.9, 11.0, 15.0,
                          17.0, 13.8, 17.4, 16.5, 14.4),
              "Endob" = c(16.5, 13.2, 13.6, 13.6, 14.0,
                          14.0, 16.0, 14.1, 11.5, 14.4,
                          16.0, 13.2, 16.6, 18.5, 14.5))

library(ggplot2)

method<-rep(c("Nasal","Endob"),each=n)
values<-c(data$Nasal, data$Endob)
patient<-factor(c(1:15))
data2<- data.frame(patient,method,values)
data2

ggplot(data2, aes(x=factor(patient), fill=method, y=values))
  geom_bar(position ="dodge",stat="identity")
```

Comment: You are mising a plus sign at the end of the `ggplot` instruction. You need to add the `geom_bar` to the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it runs fine, you just forgot the `+` between `ggplot` and `geom_bar`.

```r
ggplot(data2, aes(x=factor(patient), fill=method, y=values)) +
  geom_bar(position ="dodge",stat="identity")
```

[image]